# Prevention against Cryptolocker virus by requesting password for all installing apps in Windows 7

Tags: windows, malware, virus

Is it possible to protect Windows like Linux?

I mean, I have Ubuntu installed on my laptop and when some program wants to install something etc. the pop up shows up and I need to type the password.

So, if I click on some file in my mail client in Windows and it looks like an image or rar file, but it is a Cryptolocker virus that wants to install the pop up will show up and I can at least be warned that some program wants to be installed.

Is something like in Linux possible in Windows, so when something wants to be installed a password would be needed.

Only in Linux or it could be done in Windows 7 too?

Answer (score 4):

[UAC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/products/features/user-account-control) is Window's way of handling this. If set to the appropriate level, a pop-up appears that requires the user to provide administrative permissions to install. If the user is not an Admin, it asks for the Admin password.

Just like Linux, Windows users should NOT be running as the local admin ....

Comment: I completely agree with @schroeder's point. Requiring permissions to install is good policy for home users as well as corporate users. Just having UAC doesn't mean that malware can't install using a vulnerability though.

Comment: Depending on your UAC settings, you may not get prompted for administrative tasks at all when running as an Admin. I keep my UAC at the highest level, so I'm prompted for everything, and have it require a *password* at the prompt instead of just OK/Cancel. Having a fingerprint reader helps make the password entry less annoying. For even better protection, run as a Limited User and lock UAC down entirely - that is, set UAC to auto-reject all elevation requests from non-Admins. This way, a program can only request elevation when you explicitly use your Admin account to run it.

Comment: For requiring a password vs. OK/Cancel, and for setting UAC to auto-reject for non-Admins, check out the Security Options under Local Policies in `secpol.msc`.

Comment: Good point Iszi. UAC will only prompt if properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

One answer to these kinds of malware in general is to deny execute authority to the folder where your mail attachments are stored. http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/cryptolocker-ransomware-information#prevent

The idea is that no matter what attachments you get or from who, if they're executables, the OS prevents them from running.  If you want to run something that someone has emailed to you, you explicitly have to save it and put it somewhere other than the temp folder that your mail program used.

This is a cheap trick, and it won't save you from a malicious PDF or JPG file, but they will stop files that have been misleadingly named, such as CutePuppies.JPG.exe.  And anything you can do to reduce your chances of getting infected is an improvement in your security.

Answer (score 0):

Windows *is* protected like Linux—or at least, on Windows Vista and later, the UAC model is effectively equivalent to the run-as-unprivileged-user used by Linux/OSX/Unix.

Whilst you do need to be an admin user (elevated, in UAC terms) to install an application for all computer users, you don't need to be admin just to run an executable—either on Linux or Windows. An executable run with user rights won't be able to take over the system, but it will quite happily be able to delete, encrypt or otherwise tamper with all the documents to which the user has write access. So you definitely could port CryptoLocker to Linux.

Comment: UAC is not a security boundary as noted here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.uac.aspx and here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/e7/archive/2009/02/05/update-on-uac.aspx